# How to make git command after dash visible in intelliji?

Tags: git

[image]

so in terminal if I use dark mode, anything after - will be invisible, do you know how to make it visible ?

Comment: Not a `git` question.

Comment: Do you mean [tag:intellij-idea]? This is not about Git but it seems to be about your IDE's settings/theme or your shell/powershell's settings/theme.